# Trying to do a query with an identity which based on 2 columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

here is my current data

```
FileNumber | Type | PerYear | PerMonth
L200200      Boat   2013      1
L303000      Boat2  2013      1
L400400      Yack   2013      2
L500500      Comp   2013      2
L600600      Item   2013      3
...
L909000      Chair  2014      1
X900220      Battle 2014      2
```

I would like to have a query with kind of Identity(counter) column based on PerYear and PerMonth
Here is the result I would like to have

```
 KindOFIdentity FileNumber | Type | PerYear | PerMonth
 1              L200200      Boat   2013      1
 1              L303000      Boat2  2013      1
 2              L400400      Yack   2013      2
 2              L500500      Comp   2013      2
 3              L600600      Item   2013      3
 4 ...
 5 ...
 6 ...
 7 ...
 8 ...
 9 ...
 10 ...
 11 ...
 12 ... 
 13             L909000      Chair  2014      1
 14             X900220      Battle 2014      2
```

The query bellow dosen't give me the proper result.

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by PerYear,PerMonth order by PerYear, PerMonth) AS KindOFIdentity, Type, PerYear, PerMonth
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DENSE_RANK()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) without the `PARTITION` clause,

```
SELECT *other columns*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PerYear, PerMonth) FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO no, sometimes my answer isn't good enough because I don't provide a link to the documentation - [which is so hard to search for](http://www.bing.com/search?q=DENSE_RANK+sql+server&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=dense_rank+sql+server).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, if it was better before, please change it back, its your answer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand AHH! Bing!!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need partition. Just use ROW_NUMBER OVER(ORDER BY PerYear, PerMonth) it will return result set with ROW_NUMBER from 1 to N where N is number of rows.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for your answer, but even if I remove the partition by, I'm not getting the result I need. IF there are 2 or more identical PayYear,PayMonth the KindOfIdentity should be the same

Comment: No, ROW_NUMBER() won't give the desired results.